# Ubuntu 15.04 hangs with black screen or dead slow refresh when installed nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, 15.04

-Installed ubuntu 15.04 as a dual boot with windows 7. 
-Ubuntu installed a default graphics driver and the screen resolution could never be changed to other than 4:3.
- I changed the default drivers to nvidia as suggested by the 'additional drivers' option. 
- After that the screen just hangs once ubuntu boots and refresh is rate is slow or dead. 
Could you please help to fix this problem ?

I Use a HP pavilion Intel core2 duo with Nvidia GForce 7100 graphics.